# Should I add Guest Lecturer experience in my CV?

Tags: phd, cv

As a PhD student I have been invited to give a guest lecture in an MSc in my university in another department.

Should I add this to my CV if I intend to apply for academic jobs? If so, what should this look like in my CV? In which section would it go?

Comment: Here's a note on English grammar: One says "How should this look?" or "What should this look like?".  "How" is an adverb and "what" is a pronoun that is the object of the preposition "like".  Sometimes "How does this look?" has a connotation of "How _good_ do this look?", and "What does this look like?" avoids the ambiguity.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The more you know! Thanks! (but doesn't everything look good on a CV?(joke))

Comment: Yes you should.It means that someone wanted you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen a lot of CVs include guest lecturer. You would include it in the Teaching section of your CV.  A quick google for "guest lecturer cv" will show you some examples.

Do note, this is generally different than an invited speaker though. A Guest Lecturer comes and teaches a class where as an Invited Speaker comes to give a talk or seminar or colloquium. If this is an invited talk then you'd still list it on your CV, but in the Invited Talks section.

Comment: How would you differentiate between them? Invited speaker vs guest lecturer

Comment: @AnderBiguri Updated with a distinction.